# Continuity of a quotient function

Tags: functions, continuity

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are both functions from $R^k$ to $R^m$, which are continuous at $x\in R^k$. Suppose that $g(x)\neq 0$. Prove that the quotient function $f/g$ is defined and continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $g(x)\ne 0$, 
there is a neighborhood of $x$
where $|g(z)|>|g(x)|/2$.

Use this and the continuity of $f$